# Churn rate from multiple months

Tags: education, finance, computational-mathematics

I want to calculate the churn on a period of 7 month for a strategy. The strategy starts on 20-March so we dont have data before this point. I can calculate the monthly churn but I cant understand how can I move from this point to calculate the whole churn for the period March-September.

```
Month       Lost+Down   Previous    Churn
Mar             -           -         -
Apr             205        235     87.23%
May              40        907      4.41%
Jun             370       1542     23.99%
Jul              90       1730      5.20%
Aug             700       2948     23.74%
Sep             850       2010     42.29%
```

Comment: how is "churn" defined

Comment: Its simple as Churn = LostMoney / PreviousPeriodMoney

Comment: Thats how I calculate the monthly churn but I dont know how to convert these monthly churns to whole period churn.